# Spring Kafka, overriding max.poll.interval.ms?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to increase **max.poll.interval.ms** default value of 300000 to a greater value, due to. timeout exceptions.

However I am unable to find the property (autocomplete) in application.properties to override it.
Am I missing something out? Or I'm just using an old version of Spring Kafka (2.1.10)

```
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records     = 500
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=20000000

It worked

Comment: is there anyway to configure this parameter for a specified topic

Answer (score 0):

There is an [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html#setPollTimeout-long-), you have to set it manually. Read from the properties file and set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use consumer API to set the timeout. And configure that timeout in your property file. Consumer API provide following way to set poll duration.

```
    @Value("${pollDuration}")
    private Long pollDuration;   //read from property file

    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(pollDuration));
```

Consumer provides the different type of arguments for poll method. You can use according to your requirement.